# webpack with external code and owned code bundles

Tags: javascript, webpack, browserify, es6-module-loader, redux-thunk

It is easy to create a single bundle for development and deployment with webpack. I'd like to be able to put external dependencies into its own bundle.  Thus, I'd have "external-bundle.js" and "index-bundle.js".  The problem I have is getting an entire solution to work.  I have the working solution, but it needs a small improvement.

I write all of my code using babel and all of it is stored in files with .es extension.

Here is my directory tree:

```
/index.html
/wap/index.es
/wap/other.es
/lib/index-bundle.js
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: { index: './wap/index.es' },
    output: {path: 'lib',filename: "[name]-bundle.js"},
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.es$/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "wap"),
            ],
        }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        'react': 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        'redux': 'Redux',
        'react-redux': 'ReactRedux',
        //'redux-thunk': 'thunkMiddleware', // can't load CommonJS
        //'react-google-charts': {
        //  root: "react-google-charts",
        //  commonjs2: "Chart",
        //  amd: "Chart"
        //}
    },
    resolve: {
        // allows babel module to find files
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.es']
    }
};
```

and babel configuration for completeness:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

I was successful in including external libraries in index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/redux/dist/redux.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/react-redux/dist/react-redux.js"></script>
```

That leaves redux-thunk and react-google-charts.  I have failed to include those using html script tag, because those modules are CommonJS only.  You can see commented out externals section, because I could not figure out the reference format.

So, my only easy choice was to let those files to get included by webpack, because ES6 code is compiled into commonJS as well.

Ideally I would like to put all external dependencies into external bundle and include it with script tag in HTML file.  I'd create a bundle just for code I work on.  I was able to use this solution with browserify, but I can't figure this out at all with webpack.  I even created a separate configuration file for the external bundle, but my code failed to find objects in the external bundle.

The 2 issues are a bit connected.  I need help with:

1. externalizing redux-thunk and react-google-charts out of my index-bundle.
2. going to just two bundles

I am not using RequireJS right now and I was hoping not to start using it now.

Thank you